# Persistence after successful exploitation of a router

Tags: router

I'm "playing" with some of router at home (on an netgear for now).
I successfully managed to get root shell access on it.
The exploit starts `/bin/utelnetd -pXXXX -l/bin/sh -ixxx -d` on my router.

But every time that I restart my router, of course, I lose access.
I would like to know what I have in my arsenal to be able to get persistence on my router even after reboot.

I tried to create service in `/etc/init.d` but I'm on a squashfs FS it seems (not surprising here). I'm then in read-only. I tried `mount -o remount,rw /` which doesn't work.

What can I do here to get persistence (remount FS in r/w)?

EDIT:
Here output of mount

```
# busybox mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=127300k,nr_inodes=31825,mode=755)
devfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp type ramfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
usbdeffs on /proc/bus/usb type usbfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mtdblock18 on /tmp/openvpn type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mtdblock17 on /tmp/media/nand type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
/dev/mtdblock17 on /mnt type jffs2 (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/TMP type ramfs (rw,relatime)
devfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
proc on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/etc type ramfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/home/0db type ramfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/var/lib/sqlite type ramfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/tmpHost type ramfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/tmp type ramfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/home/0external type ramfs (rw,relatime)
devpts on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /tmp/media/nand/kwilt/hipplay/dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=777)
```

Comment: What and why do you want to persist? If possible, create own squashfs and reinstall. Are there other partitions which are already mounted rw?

Comment: I want to start arbitrary commands at startup (here /bin/utelnetd -pXXXX -l/bin/sh -ixxx -d). Why ? To avoid starting the exploit at every startup. So the idea would be to dump squashfs and reinstall it ? It needs some hardware to dump and flash firmware no ? See my edit I put mount command output.

Comment: What kind of router is that? Does it run openwrt? As described by @Artem S. Tashkinov you can probably dump without hardware access. But if you rebuild and flash the file system again and something goes wrong you maybe brick the router and then really need hardware access. There seem to be writable and persistent partitions mounted (mtdblock*). Maybe some files there can be used to run a custom command.

Comment: It's a stock netgear firmware. So no openwrt here but busybox is there and I can use it to do some diagnostics. Okay if I need hardware access to unbrick it it's no issue I can do it. Idea is just try to be able to get arbitrary custom script running at boot without hardware access. Dump would be okay but what about the write ? How can I achieve this on a running OS ?

Comment: I can't really give you an answer for this device. I guess there are ways to do a normal update of the firmware. But you'd need to find out how that works. Sometimes you can also flash via the boot loader. But this requires serial console and hardware access. If you want to risk it then save the new file system first to some tmpfs on the device and then use dd to flash the new file system at runtime. Could work if all relevant stuff required for flashing already runs from RAM. I don't know if there are published ways for restoring a Netgear router at low level.

Answer (score 1):

To flash a new ROM there are special utilities, you cannot just remount it RW. Read about OpenWRT and then routers normally have a special type of storage, so it's all quite different than what we have in the PC world. E.g. partitioning is done at a HW level, not via a "classic" x86 MBR/GPT partition table.

Comment: I knew this yes, the idea here is to know what can you do then except dump/flash new rom  on the hardware device. Also, how can you dump current squashfs FS without doing hardware stuff ? Is there a command line how can be used to dump root FS it on USB ? then flash it back ?

Comment: If it's normal USB storage, `dd`, `cat` or even `nc` (to send via network) will work. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-compressed-drive-image-over-network.html